# Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. - jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins

Hi I have an issue with my jenkins invoke command via pshell when I try to run:

```html
$restoreSecProto = [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String(([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $cred.Username, $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password))))
$basicAuthValue = "Basic $base64"
$headers = @{ 'Authorization' = $basicAuthValue }

$crumb = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headers -Uri 'https://localhost:8443/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=//crumb' -SessionVariable session -UseBasicParsing 
$session
$headers.Add('Jenkins-Crumb', $crumb.crumb)
```

error: 
Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

please note that CSRF is enabled

thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

never mind seems like by ISE session was bugged... :S

it works after i restarted ISE